# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lbfgs_ within GPLVM code

Tags: c++, fortran, lapack, unresolved-external

I am trying to build the publicly available C++ implementation of GP-LVM method in VS10
http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~neill/gplvmcpp/

which uses "fortran-2-c"ed LAPACK available here:
http://www.netlib.org/clapack/

so that I can integrate it into my PhD research later on.

I resolved all other errors yet this one I'm stuck with:

```
1>COptimisable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _lbfgs_ referenced in function "public: void __thiscall COptimisable::lbfgsOptimise(void)" (?lbfgsOptimise@COptimisable@@QAEXXZ)
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

lbfgsOptimise code:

```
void COptimisable::lbfgsOptimise()
{
  if(getVerbosity()>2)
  {
    cout << "Limited Memory BFGS Optimisation." << endl;
  }
  int nParams = getOptNumParams();
  int iflag = 0;
  int memSize = 10;
  double* Xvals = new double[nParams];
  double* work = new double[nParams*(2*memSize+1) + 2*memSize];
  double* gvals = new double[nParams];
  double* diagVals = new double[nParams];

  CMatrix X(1, nParams);
  CMatrix g(1, nParams);
  int iPrint[2] ={-1, 0};
  if(getVerbosity()>2)
  {
    iPrint[0] = 1;
  }
  double f = 0.0;
  getOptParams(X);
  while(true)
  {
    f = computeObjectiveGradParams(g);
    X.toArray(Xvals);
    g.toArray(gvals);
    lbfgs_(nParams, memSize, Xvals, f, gvals, 0, diagVals, iPrint, getObjectiveTol(), getParamTol(), work, iflag);
    if(iflag<=0)
    {
      if(iflag==-1)
      {
    cout << "Warning: lbfgsOptimise: linesearch failed." << endl;
    break;
      }
      else if(iflag == -2)
      {
    throw ndlexceptions::Error("An element of the inverse Hessian provided is not positive.");
      }
      else if(iflag == -3)
      {
    throw ndlexceptions::Error("Inproper input to lbfgs_.");
      }
    }
    else if(iflag==0)
    {
      break;
    }
    else if(iflag==1)
    {
      X.fromArray(Xvals);
      setOptParams(X);
      funcEval++;
    }
    else
    {
      throw ndlexceptions::Error("Unhandled iflag.");
    }
  }
}
```

lbfgs_ declaration:

```
// this is l-bfgs from http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/%7Enocedal/lbfgs.html
extern "C" void lbfgs_(const int& numVariables, 
               const int& numCorrections,
               double* X,
               const double& funcVal,   // set by user to be func val.
               const double* gradVals,  // set by user to be grad vals.
               const int& diagCo,
               const double* diag,
               const int iPrint[2],
               const double& prec,
               const double& xtol,
               double* W, // work vector size N(2M+1) + 2M
               int& iFlag);
```

Note:
I also experience many errors of this type:

```
1>e:\computer graphics\non-cg code\gplvm c++ - copy\gplvmcpp0p201\cndlinterfaces.h(467): warning C4290: C++ exception specification ignored except to indicate a function is not __declspec(nothrow)
```

and I get this at the end too:

```
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Comment: Looks like the code also referes to the [L-BFGS](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/lbfgs.html) Fortran library. Have you also built this library?

Comment: I can't help with the specific problem (although I think it is right that you need to build and link to the Fortran Lapack - CLAPACK just provides a C interface) but you could try a more actively maintained BLAS... OpenBlas ( https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS ) has excellent performance and is much easier to build than ATLAS so it might be worth a try.

Comment: So I found the problem: lbfgs_ has a function prototype as I showed above in ndlfortran.h but it has no corresponding function body in ndlfortran.c while all other prototypes have so. At this point I can only comment out lbfgs_ and the code builds. But I still need lbfgs_  optimization for further steps

Comment: I copied the prebuilt libraries from CLAPACK as it is told in readme of GPLVMCPP. Do you mean I also need a seperate L-BFGS library? Sorry big time noob here

Answer (score 0):

OK so I made additions to the original ndlfortran.c that comes with GPLVMCPP and finally got the solution to build. Still trying to make sure the whole application works as it should with my additions.

in case anyone else needs it..

This is what I added to the end of the original ndlfortran.c:

```
/*
 *  ME --
 * 
 *  $Id: lbfgs.c,v 1.1.1.1 2004/02/16 23:45:44 taku-ku Exp $;
 * 
 *  Copyright (C) 2001-2002  Taku Kudo <taku-ku@is.aist-nara.ac.jp>
 *  All rights reserved.
 * 
 *  This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 *  modify it under the terms of the GNU Library General Public
 *  License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 *  version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later verjsion.
 * 
 *  This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 *  Library General Public License for more details.
 * 
 *  You should have received a copy of the GNU Library General Public
 *  License along with this library; if not, write to the
 *  Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330,
 *  Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.
 * */


/*     ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*     This file contains the LBFGS algorithm and supporting routines */

/*     **************** */
/*     LBFGS SUBROUTINE */
/*     **************** */

/* Subroutine */ int lbfgs_( integer *n, integer *m, doublereal *x, doublereal *f, doublereal *g, 
                             integer *diagco, doublereal *diag, integer *iprint, doublereal *eps, doublereal *xtol, doublereal *w, integer *iflag)
{
  /* Initialized data */
  //lb3_1.mp = 6;
  //lb3_1.lp = 6;
  //lb3_1.gtol = .9;
  //lb3_1.stpmin = 1e-20;
  //lb3_1.stpmax = 1e20;

  static doublereal one = 1.0;
  static doublereal zero = 0.0;

  /* System generated locals */
  integer i__1;
  doublereal d__1;

  /* Builtin functions */
  double sqrt();

  /* Local variables */
  static doublereal beta;
  static integer inmc;
  static integer info, iscn, nfev, iycn, iter;
  static doublereal ftol;
  static integer nfun, ispt, iypt, i__, bound;
  static doublereal gnorm;

  static integer point;
  static doublereal xnorm;
  static integer cp;
  static doublereal sq, yr, ys;
  static logical finish;
  static doublereal yy;
  static integer maxfev;

  static integer npt;
  static doublereal stp, stp1;

  /* Parameter adjustments */
  --diag;
  --g;
  --x;
  --w;
  --iprint;

  /* Function Body */

  /*     INITIALIZE */
  /*     ---------- */

  if (*iflag == 0) {
    goto L10;
  }
  switch ((int)*iflag) {
  case 1:  goto L172;
  case 2:  goto L100;
  }
 L10:
  iter = 0;
  if (*n <= 0 || *m <= 0) {
    goto L196;
  }
  if (lb3_1.gtol <= 1e-4) {
    if (lb3_1.lp > 0) {}
    lb3_1.gtol = .9;
  }
  nfun = 1;
  point = 0;
  finish = FALSE_;
  if (*diagco != 0) {
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
      /* L30: */
      if (diag[i__] <= zero) {
    goto L195;
      }
    }
  } else {
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
      /* L40: */
      diag[i__] = 1.;
    }
  }

  ispt = *n + (*m << 1);
  iypt = ispt + *n * *m;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    /* L50: */
    w[ispt + i__] = -g[i__] * diag[i__];
  }
  gnorm = sqrt(ddot_(n, &g[1], &c__1, &g[1], &c__1));
  stp1 = one / gnorm;

  /*     PARAMETERS FOR LINE SEARCH ROUTINE */

  ftol = 1e-4;
  maxfev = 20;

  /*    if (iprint[1] >= 0) {
    lb1_(&iprint[1], &iter, &nfun, &gnorm, n, m, &x[1], f, &g[1], &stp, &
    finish);
    } */

  /*    -------------------- */
  /*     MAIN ITERATION LOOP */
  /*    -------------------- */

 L80:
  ++iter;
  info = 0;
  bound = iter - 1;
  if (iter == 1) {
    goto L165;
  }
  if (iter > *m) {
    bound = *m;
  }

  ys = ddot_(n, &w[iypt + npt + 1], &c__1, &w[ispt + npt + 1], &c__1);
  if (*diagco == 0) {
    yy = ddot_(n, &w[iypt + npt + 1], &c__1, &w[iypt + npt + 1], &c__1);
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
      /* L90: */
      diag[i__] = ys / yy;
    }
  } else {
    *iflag = 2;
    return 0;
  }
 L100:
  if (*diagco != 0) {
    i__1 = *n;
    for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
      /* L110: */
      if (diag[i__] <= zero) {
    goto L195;
      }
    }
  }

  /*     COMPUTE -H*G USING THE FORMULA GIVEN IN: Nocedal, J. 1980, */
  /*     "Updating quasi-Newton matrices with limited storage", */
  /*     Mathematics of Computation, Vol.24, No.151, pp. 773-782. */
  /*     --------------------------------------------------------- */

  cp = point;
  if (point == 0) {
    cp = *m;
  }
  w[*n + cp] = one / ys;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    /* L112: */
    w[i__] = -g[i__];
  }
  cp = point;
  i__1 = bound;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    --cp;
    if (cp == -1) {
      cp = *m - 1;
    }
    sq = ddot_(n, &w[ispt + cp * *n + 1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
    inmc = *n + *m + cp + 1;
    iycn = iypt + cp * *n;
    w[inmc] = w[*n + cp + 1] * sq;
    d__1 = -w[inmc];
    daxpy_(n, &d__1, &w[iycn + 1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
    /* L125: */
  }

  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    /* L130: */
    w[i__] = diag[i__] * w[i__];
  }

  i__1 = bound;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    yr = ddot_(n, &w[iypt + cp * *n + 1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
    beta = w[*n + cp + 1] * yr;
    inmc = *n + *m + cp + 1;
    beta = w[inmc] - beta;
    iscn = ispt + cp * *n;
    daxpy_(n, &beta, &w[iscn + 1], &c__1, &w[1], &c__1);
    ++cp;
    if (cp == *m) {
      cp = 0;
    }
    /* L145: */
  }

  /*     STORE THE NEW SEARCH DIRECTION */
  /*     ------------------------------ */

  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    /* L160: */
    w[ispt + point * *n + i__] = w[i__];
  }

  /*     OBTAIN THE ONE-DIMENSIONAL MINIMIZER OF THE FUNCTION */
  /*     BY USING THE LINE SEARCH ROUTINE MCSRCH */
  /*     ---------------------------------------------------- */
 L165:
  nfev = 0;
  stp = one;
  if (iter == 1) {
    stp = stp1;
  }
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    /* L170: */
    w[i__] = g[i__];
  }
 L172:
  mcsrch_(n, &x[1], f, &g[1], &w[ispt + point * *n + 1], &stp, &ftol, xtol, 
      &maxfev, &info, &nfev, &diag[1]);
  if (info == -1) {
    *iflag = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  if (info != 1) {
    goto L190;
  }
  nfun += nfev;

  /*     COMPUTE THE NEW STEP AND GRADIENT CHANGE */
  /*     ----------------------------------------- */

  npt = point * *n;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    w[ispt + npt + i__] = stp * w[ispt + npt + i__];
    /* L175: */
    w[iypt + npt + i__] = g[i__] - w[i__];
  }
  ++point;
  if (point == *m) {
    point = 0;
  }

  /*     TERMINATION TEST */
  /*     ---------------- */

  gnorm = sqrt(ddot_(n, &g[1], &c__1, &g[1], &c__1));
  xnorm = sqrt(ddot_(n, &x[1], &c__1, &x[1], &c__1));
  xnorm = max(1.,xnorm);
  if (gnorm / xnorm <= *eps) {
    finish = TRUE_;
  }

  /*    if (iprint[1] >= 0) {
    lb1_(&iprint[1], &iter, &nfun, &gnorm, n, m, &x[1], f, &g[1], &stp, &
    finish);
    }*/
  if (finish) {
    *iflag = 0;
    return 0;
  }
  goto L80;

  /*     ------------------------------------------------------------ */
  /*     END OF MAIN ITERATION LOOP. ERROR EXITS. */
  /*     ------------------------------------------------------------ */

 L190:
  *iflag = -1;
  return 0;
 L195:
  *iflag = -2;
  return 0;
 L196:
  *iflag = -3;

  return 0;
} /* lbfgs_ */

/*   ---------------------------------------------------------- */

/* Subroutine */ static int daxpy_(integer *n, doublereal *da, doublereal *dx, integer *incx, doublereal *dy, integer *incy)
{
  /* System generated locals */
  integer i__1;

  /* Local variables */
  static integer i__, m, ix, iy, mp1;


  /*     constant times a vector plus a vector. */
  /*     uses unrolled loops for increments equal to one. */
  /*     jack dongarra, linpack, 3/11/78. */


  /* Parameter adjustments */
  --dy;
  --dx;

  /* Function Body */
  if (*n <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (*da == 0.) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (*incx == 1 && *incy == 1) {
    goto L20;
  }

  /*        code for unequal increments or equal increments */
  /*          not equal to 1 */

  ix = 1;
  iy = 1;
  if (*incx < 0) {
    ix = (-(*n) + 1) * *incx + 1;
  }
  if (*incy < 0) {
    iy = (-(*n) + 1) * *incy + 1;
  }
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    dy[iy] += *da * dx[ix];
    ix += *incx;
    iy += *incy;
    /* L10: */
  }
  return 0;

  /*        code for both increments equal to 1 */


  /*        clean-up loop */

 L20:
  m = *n % 4;
  if (m == 0) {
    goto L40;
  }
  i__1 = m;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    dy[i__] += *da * dx[i__];
    /* L30: */
  }
  if (*n < 4) {
    return 0;
  }
 L40:
  mp1 = m + 1;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = mp1; i__ <= i__1; i__ += 4) {
    dy[i__] += *da * dx[i__];
    dy[i__ + 1] += *da * dx[i__ + 1];
    dy[i__ + 2] += *da * dx[i__ + 2];
    dy[i__ + 3] += *da * dx[i__ + 3];
    /* L50: */
  }
  return 0;
} /* daxpy_ */



/*   ---------------------------------------------------------- */

static doublereal ddot_(integer *n, doublereal *dx, integer *incx, doublereal *dy, integer *incy)
{
  /* System generated locals */
  integer i__1;
  doublereal ret_val;

  /* Local variables */
  static integer i__, m;
  static doublereal dtemp;
  static integer ix, iy, mp1;


  /*     forms the dot product of two vectors. */
  /*     uses unrolled loops for increments equal to one. */
  /*     jack dongarra, linpack, 3/11/78. */


  /* Parameter adjustments */
  --dy;
  --dx;

  /* Function Body */
  ret_val = 0.;
  dtemp = 0.;
  if (*n <= 0) {
    return ret_val;
  }
  if (*incx == 1 && *incy == 1) {
    goto L20;
  }

  /*        code for unequal increments or equal increments */
  /*          not equal to 1 */

  ix = 1;
  iy = 1;
  if (*incx < 0) {
    ix = (-(*n) + 1) * *incx + 1;
  }
  if (*incy < 0) {
    iy = (-(*n) + 1) * *incy + 1;
  }
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    dtemp += dx[ix] * dy[iy];
    ix += *incx;
    iy += *incy;
    /* L10: */
  }
  ret_val = dtemp;
  return ret_val;

  /*        code for both increments equal to 1 */


  /*        clean-up loop */

 L20:
  m = *n % 5;
  if (m == 0) {
    goto L40;
  }
  i__1 = m;
  for (i__ = 1; i__ <= i__1; ++i__) {
    dtemp += dx[i__] * dy[i__];
    /* L30: */
  }
  if (*n < 5) {
    goto L60;
  }
 L40:
  mp1 = m + 1;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (i__ = mp1; i__ <= i__1; i__ += 5) {
    dtemp = dtemp + dx[i__] * dy[i__] + dx[i__ + 1] * dy[i__ + 1] + dx[
                                       i__ + 2] * dy[i__ + 2] + dx[i__ + 3] * dy[i__ + 3] + dx[i__ + 
                                                                   4] * dy[i__ + 4];
    /* L50: */
  }
 L60:
  ret_val = dtemp;
  return ret_val;
} /* ddot_ */

/* Subroutine */ static int mcsrch_(integer *n, doublereal *x, doublereal *f, doublereal *g, doublereal *s, doublereal *stp, doublereal *ftol, 
                                    doublereal *xtol, integer *maxfev, integer *info, integer *nfev, doublereal *wa)
{
  /* Initialized data */

  static doublereal p5 = .5;
  static doublereal p66 = .66;
  static doublereal xtrapf = 4.;
  static doublereal zero = 0.;

  /* System generated locals */
  integer i__1;
  doublereal d__1;

  /* Local variables */
  static doublereal dgxm, dgym;
  static integer j, infoc;
  static doublereal finit, width, stmin, stmax;
  static logical stage1;
  static doublereal width1, ftest1, dg, fm, fx, fy;
  static logical brackt;
  static doublereal dginit, dgtest;
  static doublereal dgm, dgx, dgy, fxm, fym, stx, sty;

  /* Parameter adjustments */
  --wa;
  --s;
  --g;
  --x;

  /* Function Body */
  if (*info == -1) {
    goto L45;
  }
  infoc = 1;

  /*     CHECK THE INPUT PARAMETERS FOR ERRORS. */

  if (*n <= 0 || *stp <= zero || *ftol < zero || lb3_1.gtol < zero || *xtol 
      < zero || lb3_1.stpmin < zero || lb3_1.stpmax < lb3_1.stpmin || *
      maxfev <= 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  /*     COMPUTE THE INITIAL GRADIENT IN THE SEARCH DIRECTION */
  /*     AND CHECK THAT S IS A DESCENT DIRECTION. */

  dginit = zero;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
    dginit += g[j] * s[j];
    /* L10: */
  }
  if (dginit >= zero) {
    return 0;
  }

  /*     INITIALIZE LOCAL VARIABLES. */

  brackt = FALSE_;
  stage1 = TRUE_;
  *nfev = 0;
  finit = *f;
  dgtest = *ftol * dginit;
  width = lb3_1.stpmax - lb3_1.stpmin;
  width1 = width / p5;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
    wa[j] = x[j];
    /* L20: */
  }

  /*     THE VARIABLES STX, FX, DGX CONTAIN THE VALUES OF THE STEP, */
  /*     FUNCTION, AND DIRECTIONAL DERIVATIVE AT THE BEST STEP. */
  /*     THE VARIABLES STY, FY, DGY CONTAIN THE VALUE OF THE STEP, */
  /*     FUNCTION, AND DERIVATIVE AT THE OTHER ENDPOINT OF */
  /*     THE INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY. */
  /*     THE VARIABLES STP, F, DG CONTAIN THE VALUES OF THE STEP, */
  /*     FUNCTION, AND DERIVATIVE AT THE CURRENT STEP. */

  stx = zero;
  fx = finit;
  dgx = dginit;
  sty = zero;
  fy = finit;
  dgy = dginit;

  /*     START OF ITERATION. */

 L30:

  /*        SET THE MINIMUM AND MAXIMUM STEPS TO CORRESPOND */
  /*        TO THE PRESENT INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY. */

  if (brackt) {
    stmin = min(stx,sty);
    stmax = max(stx,sty);
  } else {
    stmin = stx;
    stmax = *stp + xtrapf * (*stp - stx);
  }

  /*        FORCE THE STEP TO BE WITHIN THE BOUNDS STPMAX AND STPMIN. */

  *stp = max(*stp,lb3_1.stpmin);
  *stp = min(*stp,lb3_1.stpmax);

  /*        IF AN UNUSUAL TERMINATION IS TO OCCUR THEN LET */
  /*        STP BE THE LOWEST POINT OBTAINED SO FAR. */

  if ((brackt && ((*stp <= stmin || *stp >= stmax) || *nfev >= *maxfev - 1 || 
          infoc == 0)) || (brackt && (stmax - stmin <= *xtol * stmax))) {
    *stp = stx;
  }

  /*        EVALUATE THE FUNCTION AND GRADIENT AT STP */
  /*        AND COMPUTE THE DIRECTIONAL DERIVATIVE. */
  /*        We return to main program to obtain F and G. */

  i__1 = *n;
  for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
    x[j] = wa[j] + *stp * s[j];
    /* L40: */
  }
  *info = -1;
  return 0;

 L45:
  *info = 0;
  ++(*nfev);
  dg = zero;
  i__1 = *n;
  for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
    dg += g[j] * s[j];
    /* L50: */
  }
  ftest1 = finit + *stp * dgtest;

  /*        TEST FOR CONVERGENCE. */

  if (brackt && ((*stp <= stmin || *stp >= stmax) || infoc == 0)) {
    *info = 6;
  }
  if (*stp == lb3_1.stpmax && *f <= ftest1 && dg <= dgtest) {
    *info = 5;
  }
  if (*stp == lb3_1.stpmin && (*f > ftest1 || dg >= dgtest)) {
    *info = 4;
  }
  if (*nfev >= *maxfev) {
    *info = 3;
  }
  if (brackt && stmax - stmin <= *xtol * stmax) {
    *info = 2;
  }
  if (*f <= ftest1 && abs(dg) <= lb3_1.gtol * (-dginit)) {
    *info = 1;
  }

  /*        CHECK FOR TERMINATION. */

  if (*info != 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  /*        IN THE FIRST STAGE WE SEEK A STEP FOR WHICH THE MODIFIED */
  /*        FUNCTION HAS A NONPOSITIVE VALUE AND NONNEGATIVE DERIVATIVE. */

  if (stage1 && *f <= ftest1 && dg >= min(*ftol,lb3_1.gtol) * dginit) {
    stage1 = FALSE_;
  }

  /*        A MODIFIED FUNCTION IS USED TO PREDICT THE STEP ONLY IF */
  /*        WE HAVE NOT OBTAINED A STEP FOR WHICH THE MODIFIED */
  /*        FUNCTION HAS A NONPOSITIVE FUNCTION VALUE AND NONNEGATIVE */
  /*        DERIVATIVE, AND IF A LOWER FUNCTION VALUE HAS BEEN */
  /*        OBTAINED BUT THE DECREASE IS NOT SUFFICIENT. */

  if (stage1 && *f <= fx && *f > ftest1) {

    /*           DEFINE THE MODIFIED FUNCTION AND DERIVATIVE VALUES. */

    fm = *f - *stp * dgtest;
    fxm = fx - stx * dgtest;
    fym = fy - sty * dgtest;
    dgm = dg - dgtest;
    dgxm = dgx - dgtest;
    dgym = dgy - dgtest;

    /*           CALL CSTEP TO UPDATE THE INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY */
    /*           AND TO COMPUTE THE NEW STEP. */

    mcstep_(&stx, &fxm, &dgxm, &sty, &fym, &dgym, stp, &fm, &dgm, &brackt,
        &stmin, &stmax, &infoc);

    /*           RESET THE FUNCTION AND GRADIENT VALUES FOR F. */

    fx = fxm + stx * dgtest;
    fy = fym + sty * dgtest;
    dgx = dgxm + dgtest;
    dgy = dgym + dgtest;
  } else {

    /*           CALL MCSTEP TO UPDATE THE INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY */
    /*           AND TO COMPUTE THE NEW STEP. */

    mcstep_(&stx, &fx, &dgx, &sty, &fy, &dgy, stp, f, &dg, &brackt, &
        stmin, &stmax, &infoc);
  }

  /*        FORCE A SUFFICIENT DECREASE IN THE SIZE OF THE */
  /*        INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY. */

  if (brackt) {
    if ((d__1 = sty - stx, abs(d__1)) >= p66 * width1) {
      *stp = stx + p5 * (sty - stx);
    }
    width1 = width;
    width = (d__1 = sty - stx, abs(d__1));
  }

  /*        END OF ITERATION. */

  goto L30;

  /*     LAST LINE OF SUBROUTINE MCSRCH. */

} /* mcsrch_ */

/* Subroutine */ static int mcstep_(doublereal *stx, doublereal *fx, doublereal *dx, doublereal *sty, doublereal *fy, doublereal *dy, 
                                    doublereal *stp, doublereal *fp, doublereal *dp, logical *brackt, 
                                    doublereal *stpmin, doublereal *stpmax, integer *info)
{
  /* System generated locals */
  doublereal d__1, d__2, d__3;

  /* Builtin functions */
  double sqrt();

  /* Local variables */
  static doublereal sgnd, stpc, stpf, stpq, p, q, gamma, r__, s, theta;
  static logical bound;

  *info = 0;

  /*     CHECK THE INPUT PARAMETERS FOR ERRORS. */

  if (*brackt && ((*stp <= min(*stx,*sty) || *stp >= max(*stx,*sty)) || *dx *
          (*stp - *stx) >= (float)0. || *stpmax < *stpmin)) {
    return 0;
  }

  /*     DETERMINE IF THE DERIVATIVES HAVE OPPOSITE SIGN. */

  sgnd = *dp * (*dx / abs(*dx));

  /*     FIRST CASE. A HIGHER FUNCTION VALUE. */
  /*     THE MINIMUM IS BRACKETED. IF THE CUBIC STEP IS CLOSER */
  /*     TO STX THAN THE QUADRATIC STEP, THE CUBIC STEP IS TAKEN, */
  /*     ELSE THE AVERAGE OF THE CUBIC AND QUADRATIC STEPS IS TAKEN. */

  if (*fp > *fx) {
    *info = 1;
    bound = TRUE_;
    theta = (*fx - *fp) * 3 / (*stp - *stx) + *dx + *dp;
    /* Computing MAX */
    d__1 = abs(theta), d__2 = abs(*dx), d__1 = max(d__1,d__2), d__2 = abs(
                                      *dp);
    s = max(d__1,d__2);
    /* Computing 2nd power */
    d__1 = theta / s;
    gamma = s * sqrt(d__1 * d__1 - *dx / s * (*dp / s));
    if (*stp < *stx) {
      gamma = -gamma;
    }
    p = gamma - *dx + theta;
    q = gamma - *dx + gamma + *dp;
    r__ = p / q;
    stpc = *stx + r__ * (*stp - *stx);
    stpq = *stx + *dx / ((*fx - *fp) / (*stp - *stx) + *dx) / 2 * (*stp - 
                                   *stx);
    if ((d__1 = stpc - *stx, abs(d__1)) < (d__2 = stpq - *stx, abs(d__2)))
      {
    stpf = stpc;
      } else {
    stpf = stpc + (stpq - stpc) / 2;
      }
    *brackt = TRUE_;

    /*     SECOND CASE. A LOWER FUNCTION VALUE AND DERIVATIVES OF */
    /*     OPPOSITE SIGN. THE MINIMUM IS BRACKETED. IF THE CUBIC */
    /*     STEP IS CLOSER TO STX THAN THE QUADRATIC (SECANT) STEP, */
    /*     THE CUBIC STEP IS TAKEN, ELSE THE QUADRATIC STEP IS TAKEN. */

  } else if (sgnd < (float)0.) {
    *info = 2;
    bound = FALSE_;
    theta = (*fx - *fp) * 3 / (*stp - *stx) + *dx + *dp;
    /* Computing MAX */
    d__1 = abs(theta), d__2 = abs(*dx), d__1 = max(d__1,d__2), d__2 = abs(
                                      *dp);
    s = max(d__1,d__2);
    /* Computing 2nd power */
    d__1 = theta / s;
    gamma = s * sqrt(d__1 * d__1 - *dx / s * (*dp / s));
    if (*stp > *stx) {
      gamma = -gamma;
    }
    p = gamma - *dp + theta;
    q = gamma - *dp + gamma + *dx;
    r__ = p / q;
    stpc = *stp + r__ * (*stx - *stp);
    stpq = *stp + *dp / (*dp - *dx) * (*stx - *stp);
    if ((d__1 = stpc - *stp, abs(d__1)) > (d__2 = stpq - *stp, abs(d__2)))
      {
    stpf = stpc;
      } else {
    stpf = stpq;
      }
    *brackt = TRUE_;

    /*     THIRD CASE. A LOWER FUNCTION VALUE, DERIVATIVES OF THE */
    /*     SAME SIGN, AND THE MAGNITUDE OF THE DERIVATIVE DECREASES. */
    /*     THE CUBIC STEP IS ONLY USED IF THE CUBIC TENDS TO INFINITY */
    /*     IN THE DIRECTION OF THE STEP OR IF THE MINIMUM OF THE CUBIC */
    /*     IS BEYOND STP. OTHERWISE THE CUBIC STEP IS DEFINED TO BE */
    /*     EITHER STPMIN OR STPMAX. THE QUADRATIC (SECANT) STEP IS ALSO */
    /*     COMPUTED AND IF THE MINIMUM IS BRACKETED THEN THE THE STEP */
    /*     CLOSEST TO STX IS TAKEN, ELSE THE STEP FARTHEST AWAY IS TAKEN. */

  } else if (abs(*dp) < abs(*dx)) {
    *info = 3;
    bound = TRUE_;
    theta = (*fx - *fp) * 3 / (*stp - *stx) + *dx + *dp;
    /* Computing MAX */
    d__1 = abs(theta), d__2 = abs(*dx), d__1 = max(d__1,d__2), d__2 = abs(
                                      *dp);
    s = max(d__1,d__2);

    /*        THE CASE GAMMA = 0 ONLY ARISES IF THE CUBIC DOES NOT TEND */
    /*        TO INFINITY IN THE DIRECTION OF THE STEP. */

    /* Computing MAX */
    /* Computing 2nd power */
    d__3 = theta / s;
    d__1 = 0., d__2 = d__3 * d__3 - *dx / s * (*dp / s);
    gamma = s * sqrt((max(d__1,d__2)));
    if (*stp > *stx) {
      gamma = -gamma;
    }
    p = gamma - *dp + theta;
    q = gamma + (*dx - *dp) + gamma;
    r__ = p / q;
    if (r__ < (float)0. && gamma != (float)0.) {
      stpc = *stp + r__ * (*stx - *stp);
    } else if (*stp > *stx) {
      stpc = *stpmax;
    } else {
      stpc = *stpmin;
    }
    stpq = *stp + *dp / (*dp - *dx) * (*stx - *stp);
    if (*brackt) {
      if ((d__1 = *stp - stpc, abs(d__1)) < (d__2 = *stp - stpq, abs(
                                     d__2))) {
    stpf = stpc;
      } else {
    stpf = stpq;
      }
    } else {
      if ((d__1 = *stp - stpc, abs(d__1)) > (d__2 = *stp - stpq, abs(
                                     d__2))) {
    stpf = stpc;
      } else {
    stpf = stpq;
      }
    }

    /*     FOURTH CASE. A LOWER FUNCTION VALUE, DERIVATIVES OF THE */
    /*     SAME SIGN, AND THE MAGNITUDE OF THE DERIVATIVE DOES */
    /*     NOT DECREASE. IF THE MINIMUM IS NOT BRACKETED, THE STEP */
    /*     IS EITHER STPMIN OR STPMAX, ELSE THE CUBIC STEP IS TAKEN. */

  } else {
    *info = 4;
    bound = FALSE_;
    if (*brackt) {
      theta = (*fp - *fy) * 3 / (*sty - *stp) + *dy + *dp;
      /* Computing MAX */
      d__1 = abs(theta), d__2 = abs(*dy), d__1 = max(d__1,d__2), d__2 = 
    abs(*dp);
      s = max(d__1,d__2);
      /* Computing 2nd power */
      d__1 = theta / s;
      gamma = s * sqrt(d__1 * d__1 - *dy / s * (*dp / s));
      if (*stp > *sty) {
    gamma = -gamma;
      }
      p = gamma - *dp + theta;
      q = gamma - *dp + gamma + *dy;
      r__ = p / q;
      stpc = *stp + r__ * (*sty - *stp);
      stpf = stpc;
    } else if (*stp > *stx) {
      stpf = *stpmax;
    } else {
      stpf = *stpmin;
    }
  }

  /*     UPDATE THE INTERVAL OF UNCERTAINTY. THIS UPDATE DOES NOT */
  /*     DEPEND ON THE NEW STEP OR THE CASE ANALYSIS ABOVE. */

  if (*fp > *fx) {
    *sty = *stp;
    *fy = *fp;
    *dy = *dp;
  } else {
    if (sgnd < (float)0.) {
      *sty = *stx;
      *fy = *fx;
      *dy = *dx;
    }
    *stx = *stp;
    *fx = *fp;
    *dx = *dp;
  }

  /*     COMPUTE THE NEW STEP AND SAFEGUARD IT. */

  stpf = min(*stpmax,stpf);
  stpf = max(*stpmin,stpf);
  *stp = stpf;
  if (*brackt && bound) {
    if (*sty > *stx) {
      /* Computing MIN */
      d__1 = *stx + (*sty - *stx) * (float).66;
      *stp = min(d__1,*stp);
    } else {
      /* Computing MAX */
      d__1 = *stx + (*sty - *stx) * (float).66;
      *stp = max(d__1,*stp);
    }
  }
  return 0;

  /*     LAST LINE OF SUBROUTINE MCSTEP. */

} /* mcstep_ */
```

and this is the changed beginning of my new ndlfortran.c until first subroutine psi_ :

```
#include "f2c.h"

/* Table of constant values */

#ifdef _FORTRAN_MAIN_FIX
    int MAIN__() {return 0;};
#endif



typedef long int integer;
typedef unsigned long int uinteger;
typedef char *address;
typedef short int shortint;
typedef float real;
typedef double doublereal;
typedef long int logical;
typedef short int shortlogical;
typedef char logical1;
typedef char integer1;

#define TRUE_ (1)
#define FALSE_ (0)
#define abs(x) ((x) >= 0 ? (x) : -(x))
#define min(a,b) ((a) <= (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define max(a,b) ((a) >= (b) ? (a) : (b))

/* Common Block Declarations */
 struct lb3_1_ {
  integer mp, lp;
  doublereal gtol, stpmin, stpmax;
} ; 

/* Table of constant values */
 static struct lb3_1_ lb3_1 = {  6, 6, .9, 1e-20,1e20};
static integer c__1 = 1;

static doublereal ddot_  ();
static int daxpy_ ();
static int mcsrch_();
static int mcstep_();

static integer c__0 = 0;
```